# how to correct commutative diagram

Tags: tikz-cd

I have a commutative diagram

```
\[\textbf{As} ~\bar{\longrightarrow} \arrow{d} &  \textbf{Lie} \arrow{d} \\
\textbf{Dias}~ \bar{\longrightarrow} &\textbf{ Leib}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

be after running, it does not provide a correct diagram. Can you please help me to correct that?

Comment: As always on this site, please post a full minimal example instead of a sniplet. This makes it a lot easier for others to copy your code and test it. Thus, please help us help you.

Comment: You missed `\begin{tikzcd}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\mathbf{As} \arrow[r,"-"] \arrow[d] & \mathbf{Lie} \arrow[d] \\
\mathbf{Dias} \arrow[r,"-"] & \mathbf{Leib}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Silently changed to math fonts in math mode :-)